# Can not change rotation of prefabs

Tags: unity

```
var angle = temp.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            angle.y = 90;

temp.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (angle);
```

I have tried this and some other variation to change the rotation of the instantiated prefab but it does not work at all.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does it do? Do you have the script attached?

Comment: Yes I have attached the script, prefabs are being instantiated but not rotated as I need them to

Comment: What is the temp variable?

Comment: It's the Gameobject in which reference to instantiated prefab is stored.

Comment: Have you tried just attaching a script to the prefab and sending a message to it to rotate?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an already rotated object by using

```
GameObject instance = GameObject.Instantiate (prefab, position, rotation)
```

where `rotation` is a `Quaternion` you compute earlier in the code like this:

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 90, 0)
```